# Invalidate cache on new order

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft2

I have a list of orders from Commerce 1 (Craft 2) in the frontend.

I want to invalidate the cache when a new order is placed but it doesn't work:

```
{% set latestOrder = craft.commerce.orders.first() %}

{% cache until latestOrder.dateOrdered  %}
   Last Updated: {{ orders.dateOrdered.first() | date('D d.m.Y - H:i') }}
   {# stuff #}
{% endcache %}
```

The `Last Updated` tag shows always the latest browser reload. What's the error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are only caching until the `dateOrdered` of the latest order. That means that viewing the page will always be ahead of the cache time.

You could look to do the following:

```
{% set latestOrder = craft.commerce.orders.order('dateOrdered DESC').first() %}
{% set cacheKey = 'orders-' ~ latestOrder.dateOrdered|date('U') %}

{% cache using key cacheKey %}
  {% set orders = craft.commerce.orders.order('dateOrdered DESC').find() %}
  <ul>
    {% for order in orders %}
      <li>{{ order.id }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endcache %}
```

This creates a cache key based on the date of the latest order. Therefore, when there is a new order this key will change.